# How to use a decorator of a descriptor within a sub class

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor, python-descriptors

I was wondering if it possible to use a descriptor's decorator within a subclass.

```
class Descriptor():
    def __get__(self, instance_obj, objtype):
        raise Exception('ouch.')
    def decorate(self, f):
        print('decorate', f)
        return f

class A():
    my_attr = Descriptor()

class B():
    @my_attr.decorate
    def foo(self):
        print('hey, whatsup?')

# --> NameError: name 'my_attr' is not defined
```

This, of course, does not work since `my_attr` is undefined within the class definition of `B`.

Next I tried:

```
class B():
    @A.my_attr.decorate
    def foo(self):
        print('hey, whatsup?')

# --> Exception: ouch.
```

But, this approach invokes the descriptor `__get__` method (where the `instance_obj` argument is `None`) and therefore the test Exception is fired. To access the decorator one could check for the `instance_obj` to be `None` an return the descriptor itself:

```
def __get__(self, instance_obj, objtype):
    if instance_obj is None:
        return self
    raise Exception('avoid this')
# --> decorate <function B.foo at 0x1021dd7b8>
```

It works! But is it plausible or is there a way to use the decorator within the class definition of `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bypass the descriptor protocol altogether by retrieving the original object from the `__dict__` mapping of the class:

```
A.__dict__['my_attr'].decorate
```

or cleaner, using `vars()`:

```
vars(A)['my_attr'].decorate
```

However, the `@` decorator syntax doesn't allow for subscriptions (you are given only simpler expressions with attribute access and a single call at the end), so you'd have to extract the dictionary *first*:

```
_A_my_attr = vars(A)['my_attr']
@_A_my_attr.decorate
def foo(self):
    # ...
```

However, unless you must capture the binding to a class, it is better to guard for the first argument to `__get__` being `None`, as you discovered. This is exactly what `property` objects or functions do.

Comment: If he wanted a global, we would not put the decorator inside a class